# Table options do not contain an option key 'connector'

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to create a hive table using flink sql client.

I could create the table t2 successfully, but when i query t2, it complains

```
Table options do not contain an option key 'connector' for discovering a connector.
```

I have set the execution type to be batch in the  conf/sql-client-defaults.yaml file,

I would ask what the problem is here. Thanks!

```
Flink SQL> use testdb1;

Flink SQL>  create table t2(id int,name string);
[INFO] Table has been created.

Flink SQL> select * from t2;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Table options do not contain an option key 'connector' for discovering a connector.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Flink doesn't know where to find or put t2 -- it needs to be associated with some data source or sink, such as a file, or kafka topic, or jdbc database. You also need to specify a format, so that the data can be serialized / deserialized. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE KafkaTable (
  `id` BIGINT,
  `name` STRING
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'data',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'csv'
)
```

See the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/) for the specific connector you are using for more information.

In the specific case of Hive, see [Hive Read & Write](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/hive/hive_read_write.html). There's an example of setting up a table for writing to Hive [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/hive/hive_read_write.html#writing), which looks something like this:

```sql
SET table.sql-dialect=hive;
CREATE TABLE hive_table (
  id BIGINT,
  name STRING
) PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING, hr STRING) STORED AS parquet TBLPROPERTIES (
  'partition.time-extractor.timestamp-pattern'='$dt $hr:00:00',
  'sink.partition-commit.trigger'='partition-time',
  'sink.partition-commit.delay'='1 h',
  'sink.partition-commit.policy.kind'='metastore,success-file'
);
```