# another case of "Table options do not contain an option key 'connector'"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have read the link [Table options do not contain an option key 'connector'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387785/table-options-do-not-contain-an-option-key-connector)

it said we should set the format.

But My Scene is datagen->hive.
Here's my completed example(it's wrong Now)

```
drop table if exists datagen;
CREATE TABLE datagen (
 f_sequence INT,
 f_random INT,
 f_random_str STRING,
 ts AS localtimestamp,
 WATERMARK FOR ts AS ts
) WITH (
 'connector' = 'datagen',

 -- optional options --

 'rows-per-second'='5',

 'fields.f_sequence.kind'='sequence',
 'fields.f_sequence.start'='1',
 'fields.f_sequence.end'='50',-- 这个地方限制了一共会产生的条数

 'fields.f_random.min'='1',
 'fields.f_random.max'='50',

 'fields.f_random_str.length'='10'
);

SET table.sql-dialect=hive;
drop table if exists hive_table;

CREATE TABLE hive_table (
  f_sequence INT,
  f_random INT,
  f_random_str STRING
) PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING, hr STRING, mi STRING) STORED AS parquet TBLPROPERTIES (
  'partition.time-extractor.timestamp-pattern'='$dt $hr:$mi:00',
  'sink.partition-commit.trigger'='partition-time',
  'sink.partition-commit.delay'='1 min',
  'sink.partition-commit.policy.kind'='metastore,success-file'
);


Flink SQL> insert into hive_table select f_sequence,f_random,f_random_str ,DATE_FORMAT(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), DATE_FORMAT(ts, 'HH') ,DATE_FORMAT(ts, 'mm') from datagen;
[INFO] Submitting SQL update statement to the cluster...
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Table options do not contain an option key 'connector' for discovering a connector.
```

Is the solution from above link  suitable for this case?

Need your help,Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

please use `SET table.sql-dialect=default;` before call `insert into hive_table...`, the statement `insert into hive_table...` using datagen connector which hive dialect should not support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I have already set this ,but no luck~